# I receive a 403 error when developing with VM and Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, virtual-machine

I currently use VM to develop a project, and centOS is installed in that VM. I install Apache on centOS run in VM. I decide to use the mounted folder of VM as the htdocs folder, and I have changed httpd.conf. But when I try using Chrome to access the mounted folder via the IP address of my VM, I receive a 403 error. There is no problem if I don't change the path of the htdocs folder.
I know maybe permissions of the mounted folder prevent me from accessing it, so I try to use sudo chmod to change those permissions, but it doesn't work, the permissions can't be changed. Help me please!

Comment: snippets from you httpd.conf would help us find your problem

Comment: <Directory "/media/sf_workspace">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Add configurations in the question, using code formatting.  Not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are coming across an issue directly related to an actively enforced SELINUX policy on the web server. The mounted directory, along with the files stored in it must have the proper SELINUX context in order for Apache to work. You may verify this hypothesis by peeking at relevant log files in /var/log/audit/.